# Should the refreshToken be stored on the database?

Tags: mysql, redis, jwt, nestjs, refresh-token

I am thinking about how to store the refresh token.

The token is validated in NestJS, so I thought that it was necessary to store it in MySQL or Redis.

If we save, we should be able to identify multiple devices, and if the user exits without logging out, we need to retain unnecessary data until the expiration of the refresh token.

For this reason, I thought it might not be necessary.

If I'm thinking wrong, please let me know!

Comment: Is this in relation to, specifically, the JWT refresh token?

Comment: @tadman When a user logs in, an access token and a refresh token are sent and stored in redis. After that, when the access token expires, refresh the access token with refresh token.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a question. That's a statement of fact?

Comment: @tadman This is the login process for my service. The question is whether it is necessary to store the refresh token in redis during this process!

Comment: Sounds like it has to be stored somewhere, and Redis, with an appropriate TTL, isn't the worst idea. Is it working that way? If so, what's the issue? If you're trying to reduce dependencies and are looking to consolidate on MySQL, that's something more specific.

Comment: @tadman I'm wondering if the refresh token must be stored on the server. If I have to save, why do I have to save?

Comment: Remember HTTP is request/response, so for data like this that persists between requests, it has to go *somewhere*. The server is ephemeral, and further, there might be more than one server involved, either process or physical. The only way to coordinate between those instances is via a backing store like MySQL or Redis.

Comment: @tadman Sorry. I tried to understand the answer, but I don't understand.TT..

Comment: Not going to take offense to that, but you should read up more on the separation between server and state, where "state" is "persistent data" that survives long after the server's been restarted, etc.

Comment: @tadman thank you! This answer made me understand!

Comment: @tadman Sorry. Just one more question. If I allow login from multiple devices, is it ok to save it in redis in the form of `(key)userId-access_token : (value) refresh_token` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily store a refresh or accessToken in a database, but usually you store the idToken or the so called [userInfo](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfoResponse) response instead.

However, you do store the response of the OIDC provider. Usually they expose a jwks endpoint that allows you to verify if the incoming token is signed by them. A package that solves this for you is [jwks-rsa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwks-rsa). You want this behavior, because you don't want to verify the incoming token, over and over again at the provider. Instead you just want to verify if the token is valid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can extract userInfo through nestjs guard. If so, is it correct that there is no need to save it?

Comment: You should always cache the userinfo response. Typically you use the `jti` claim from the accessToken as key and the userinfo response as value in for example Redis. You cache the userinfo response for the duration of the accessToken's `exp` time. You can retreive the values by decoding the accessToken, for an example see: https://jwt.io/.